# How to filter if array contains value in between two numbers using Mongodb?

Tags: mongodb

```
<pre>
[{
        "_id" : ObjectId("abc123"),
        "data" : [50,60,70]
},
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("abc123"),
        "data" : [70,80,90]
}]
</pre>
```

**I want to filter using mongodb to find records that contains data between 55 and 65. The result should be below as this record contains data between 55 and 65 which is 60.**

```
<pre>
    [{
            "_id" : ObjectId("abc123"),
            "data" : [50,60,70]
    }]
</pre>
```

Answer (score 0):

[playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/q84vdVzqxxg)

```
db.collection.find({
  data: {
    $gte: 55,
    $lte: 60
  }
})
```

It's an `and` condition with `gte, lte`.